# How to access a character in a character array

Tags: c, string, pointers, char, printf

```
#include< stdio.h>

int main()
{
    char *name[] = { "hello" , "world" , "helloworld" };    /* character array */       
    printf("%s", (*(name+2)+7));
    return 0;
}
```

The above code prints out "rld". I wants to print only "r".

Comment: so use %c instead, and another *

Comment: the compiler should warn you for this.

Comment: @Jean-FrançoisFabre Why? What for?

Comment: This is not a good duplicate for that question...

Comment: @Jean-FrançoisFabre: this may well be a duplicate, but the linked duplicate doesn't look anywhere near correct ?

Comment: ok, now I've re-read the question. Not a duplicate of that, I admit. fast lane reopen :) (but the answers are already there, mind)

Answer (score 4):

For starters you do not have a character array. You have an array of pointers. Also it would be better to declare the type of array elements like

```
const char *
```

because string literals are immutable in C.

And instead of the `%s` specifier you need to use the specifier `%c` to output just a character.

A simple and clear way to output the target character of the third element of the array is

```
printf("%c", name[2][7]);
```

Or using the pointer arithmetic you can write

```
printf("%c", *(*( name + 2 )+7 ) );
```

Here is a demonstrative program

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main(void) 
{
    const char *name[] = 
    { 
        "hello" , "world" , "helloworld" 

    };

    printf( "%c\n", *( * ( name + 2 ) + 7 ) );
    printf( "%c\n", name[2][7] );

    return 0;
}
```

Its output is

```
r
r
```

Take into account that according to the C Standard the function `main` without parameters shall be declared like

```
int main( void )
```

Comment: " function main without parameters shall be declared like int main( void )"  Or in some implementation-defined manner. That is, if you are assuming hosted implementation. On a freestanding implementation, the form of main is always implementation-defined.

Answer (score 3):

Use %c:

```
printf("%c", *(*(name+2)+7));
```

Comment: Thank you... tipped too fast :)

Comment: you could elaborate more on _how_ you have to use `%c`

Answer (score 1):

You can use simple trick as follows,

```
printf("%c", name[2][7]);
```

And as you want character, you should use `%c`.
Here is working [demo](https://onlinegdb.com/SyW_sc8FG).